# sequelize is not returning the associated table data as an object

Tags: sequelize.js, associations, feathersjs

I am using feathers with sequelize.js for my backend

I have two models with association

**lines.model.js**

```
const lines = sequelizeClient.define(
    "lines",
    {
      line_number: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  lines.associate = function (models) {
    const { machines } = models;
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    lines.hasMany(machines);
  };
```

and

**machines.model.js**

```
const machines = sequelizeClient.define(
    "machines",
    {
      machine_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      lineId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      url: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  machines.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    const { lines } = models;
    machines.belongsTo(lines);
  };
```

Inside the hook function of the lines service

**lines.hooks.js**

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [authenticate("jwt")],
    find: [
      (context) => {
        // Get the Sequelize instance. In the generated application via:
        const sequelize = context.app.get("sequelizeClient");
        const { machines } = sequelize.models;
        sequelize.raw = true;
        console.log(machines);
        context.params.sequelize = {
          include: [{ model: machines }],
        };

        return context;
      },
    ],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },
};
```

When I call the rest api of the lines service via postman (`url:[GET] http://localhost:3030/lines` )
It returns

```
{
    "total": 4,
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "line_number": "M11",
            "machines.id": null,
            "machines.machine_name": null,
            "machines.lineId": null,
            "machines.url": null,
            
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "line_number": "M22",
            "machines.id": null,
            "machines.machine_name": null,
            "machines.lineId": null,
            "machines.url": null,
            
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "line_number": "M12",
            "machines.id": null,
            "machines.machine_name": null,
            "machines.lineId": null,
            "machines.url": null,
            
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "line_number": "M21",
            "machines.id": 16,
            "machines.machine_name": "MULTI4",
            "machines.lineId": 3,
            "machines.url": "http://192.168.10.5/webservice/cwebservice.asmx?wsdl",
            
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "line_number": "M21",
            "machines.id": 15,
            "machines.machine_name": "MCAL4",
            "machines.lineId": 3,
            "machines.url": "http://192.168.10.4/webservice/cwebservice.asmx?wsdl",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the machines added to the lines and if a line have more than one machine it will return two or more times
How can I make it like this

```
{
    "total": 4,
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "line_number": "M11",
            "machines" : []
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "line_number": "M22",
            "machines" : []
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "line_number": "M12",
            "machines" : []
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "line_number": "M21",
            "machines" : [{
                   {
                      "id": 16,
                      "machine_name": "MULTI4",
                      "lineId": 3,
                      "url": "http://192.168.10.5/webservice/cwebservice.asmx?wsdl",
                   },
                   {
                      "id": 15,
                      "machine_name": "MCAL4",
                      "lineId": 3,
                      "url": "http://192.168.10.4/webservice/cwebservice.asmx?wsdl",
                   }
             }]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution by adding the following line in the hook function

```
Object.assign(context.params.sequelize, { raw: false });
```

so the hook file become like this

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [authenticate("jwt")],
    find: [
      (context) => {
        // Get the Sequelize instance. In the generated application via:
        const sequelize = context.app.get("sequelizeClient");
        const { machines } = sequelize.models;
        sequelize.raw = true;
        context.params.sequelize = {
          include: [{ model: machines, nested: true }],
        };
        Object.assign(context.params.sequelize, { raw: false });
        return context;
      },
    ],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: [],
  },
};
```